# Why are eggshells so strong?

Tags: everyday-life, stress-strain

The usual explanation that someone can find on internet is that it is shaped like an arch, but it is not exactly an arch.

Does anybody knows something more on this?

Comment: I found a paper: https://www.researchgate.net/publication/287486407_The_effect_of_the_egg%27s_shape_on_the_stress_distribution_in_the_eggshell_at_internal_pressure_loading

Comment: From a biological perspective, evolution favoured strong eggs.

Comment: @KrishnanandJ well, that's like anthropic principle, but applied to egg-laying animals: seems to explain everything, but doesn't give any insight whatsoever.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is the same principle as applies to an arch. The curve of an arch is such that forces are transmitted along the curve of the arch. Ideal curves for this are the [catenary arch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catenary_arch), and for a bridge supporting weight, the cycloid, most famously used in the ["New" London Bridge (1831–1967)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/London_Bridge#%22New%22_London_Bridge_(1831%E2%80%931967))

The difference with an eggshell is that it is a 2D surface in three dimensions, and it transmits compression forces in the surface. It is only really strong under compression of the endpoints, where forces are transmitted symmetrically, and when it is squeezed symmetrically from all directions by the output canal when being laid. Not so strong when squeezed in a single axis from the sides.

Comment: the egg has to go through the output canal, whole , so that it can be that is why it is shaped this way, and the compression is along the axis. It should be whole so it can be incubated until the chicken is ready to face the world.

Comment: good point. I have expanded slightly.

Comment: thank you very much